# Error adding qgis.org repository public key to apt keyring

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

The old QGIS key ring `qgis-2017.gpg.key` is expired and generates a warning during `apt update` today.

Following the [QGIS instructions](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html), I tried to update the key as follows:

```
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3
```

But instead of the normal output, I get an error:

```
$ wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
--2019-08-16 18:36:35--  https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key
Resolving qgis.org (qgis.org)... 104.27.138.220, 104.27.139.220, 2606:4700:30::681b:8bdc, ...
Connecting to qgis.org (qgis.org)|104.27.138.220|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1839 (1.8K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================>]   1.80K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-08-16 18:36:35 (33.3 MB/s) - written to stdout [1839/1839]

gpg: key 51F523511C7028C3: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: no writable keyring found: Not found
gpg: error reading '[stdin]': General error
gpg: import from '[stdin]' failed: General error
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

*How can I fix the error please?*

Comment: what apt repository are you using? The one for "cosmic" still uses the expired 2017 key :-(

Comment: @Dakatine I am using `deb https://qgis.org/debian  bionic main` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately it is not working here on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Based on old notes, the following seems to work:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 51F523511C7028C3
```

-- Update --

As of August 2020:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key F7E06F06199EF2F2
```

As of August 2021:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 46B5721DBBD2996A
```

Or alternatively, as pointed out by 4ndts's answer (and in the updated documentation):

```
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-$(date +%Y).gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import
```

The above determines year from current date. If that's not accurate, the latest is:

```
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2022.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04 this also solved the following problem for me.  W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://qgis.org/debian disco InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51F523511C7028C3

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) this is not working. When I try to update I get "W: Failed to fetch http://qgis.org/ubuntugis/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1565999960"

Answer (score 9):

After you have verified the fingerprint you forgot to add the key to apt with:

```
gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Read the [QGIS documentation](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html). All the instructions are:

```
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3
gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 5):

QGIS Key is rotated every year, if there is an error like this, u may check follow link whether it has new key:
https://download.qgis.org/downloads/

On the other hand, the fingerprint also change accordingly, example in year 2021, it was ***46B5721DBBD2996A***, and 2022, it was ***D155B8E6A419C5BE***

It's easy to generate new download link for every year, but I cannot find a way to get fingerprint automatically, I found a trick by looking at the error

**1. First I use 2022 key with 2021 key by executing the command below:**

```bash
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2022.gpg.key | gpg --import \
    && gpg --export --armor 46B5721DBBD2996A | apt-key add -
```

**2. then I've an error which mentions gpt key, as below:**

```bash
gpg: key D155B8E6A419C5BE: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key D155B8E6A419C5BE: "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2022-2027) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

**3. Then I just update my command as below, and then it works**

```bash
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2022.gpg.key | gpg --import \
    && gpg --export --armor D155B8E6A419C5BE | apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in November 2022:

```
curl https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2022.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 1):

`gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3` returns uid [ expired].

There's a 2021 key:

```
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2021.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import

sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg
```