# Can't install QGIS in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: installation, ubuntu

I've tried installing the latest QGIS relaease on my Ubuntu according to the installation guide on the website (which has worked before).

```
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2021.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import

sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg
```

I got this error code:

```
gpg: key 46B5721DBBD2996A: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 46B5721DBBD2996A: "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2021) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

When trying to install now, using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main"
```

I get:

```
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: GPG error: http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071 NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
E: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Doesn anyone have an idea what I could do? I tried deleting the old keys in sources.list, but it isn't working...

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see it has nothing to do with QGIS but that Google repo for `cloud-sdk`. Remove or fix that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

From [Error adding qgis.org repository public key to apt keyring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332245/error-adding-qgis-org-repository-public-key-to-apt-keyring) :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 46B5721DBBD2996A
```

The key for the Google cloud-sdk is a different key, but the same error.